# How can I add android StateListAnimator in style.xml file?

Tags: android, xml, shadow

I want to remove shadows from button so I am defining a style for button and adding stateListAnimator=@null tag in the style.xml file file but it's not working. But, when I add stateListAnimator=@null while defining button in it;s layout file, its working perfectly.

This is the code of button style -

```
<style name="ServiceButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/medium_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I've had the same problem, adnd I think I found the solution.


The attribute will work via `style="@style/ActionButton.Important"`, but not via `android:theme="@style/ActionButton.Important"`